# how to find a bitangent, point of concavity and center of gravity of concavity?

Tags: matlab, math, geometry

I am trying to find the bitangent to a irregular region and corresponding point of concavity and center of concavity using matlab. 
Here I have the coordinates of boundary of the region and the coordinates of boundary lying on convex hull of the region.
This bitangent would be one of the line segments of convex hull of the region.
If I shrink the convex hull it is not overlapping with the inner coordinates of the region, making it difficult to identify other parameters.

I have also tried removing the boundary point of the region and creating a convex hull of remaining points. But the shape of the hull changed so it cannot assure the correct result.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you post your source code and an example of a correct input and output?

Answer (score 0):

1. **center of curvature**

   [image: center of curvature]

   I am pretty sure I posted here one answer about this but cant find it now :( so here it is again. Take 2 neighboring lines of the mesh and cast normals from their mid-points. Where they intersect there is the center of curvature. If it is inside or outside the mesh tells you about convexity or use winding rule ...

   if this is not the center of concavity you want then add more info about it ...
2. **TBN**

   `normal` is the blue line (radius) it lies on line from center of curvature to line join point use direction you need.

   `bitangent` is perpendicular to one line and `normal`

   ```
   bitangent = normal x (line.p1-line.p0)
   ```

   `tangent` is perpendicular to `normal` and `binormal`

   ```
   tangent = bitangent x normal
   ```

   it is good idea to make **TBN** vector unit ones. Use the direction you need  to invert it just swap the operands in vector multiply or multiply vector by `-1` scalar.