# Change arc's shape by moving only one point

Tags: c++, geometry, automatic-ref-counting, trigonometry

I'm having some troubles with changing arc's shape by moving only one of its grab points.

I got three points: center point `center`, starting point `start` and ending point `end`. There are only two possible actions:

- change `start` while `end` remains untouched,
- change `end` while `start` remains untouched.

I figured out that:

1. Changing a position of one of these points,
2. Recalculating the radius using the old center point and the untouched point using this formula:

   ```
   if (start.changed) {
       radius = std::sqrt(
           (center.x - end.x) * (center.x - end.x) +
           (center.y - end.y) * (center.y - end.y)
       );
   }
   if (end.changed) {
       radius = std::sqrt(
           (center.x - start.x) * (center.m_x - start.x) +
           (center.y - start.y) * (center.m_y - start.y)
       );
   }
   ```
3. Recalculating arc's angles with this formula:

   ```
   startAngle = std::atan2(start.y - center.y, start.x - center.x);
   endAngle   = std::atan2(end.y - center.y, end.x - center.x);
   ```

Allows me to modify its angle freely. I'm not able to adjust its size though. I thought that modifying the center point, before performing steps `2` and `3` from the list, would solve the problem.

Unfortunately, every solution I tried failed and I'm helpless now. I suspect that I have to measure an angle between `center`, `start` and `end` between steps `1` and `2`, and then calculate new center using that angle. Is that correct?

[image: This is how it currently looks in different states]
[This is how I'd like it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqyLK.jpg)

Comment: I don't see clear rules - what parameters should be changed. If P1=circle center remains the same - what you want to preserve and what to change?

Comment: @MBo I'd like to change a position of `end` or `start`. This changes arc's diameter. But at the same time, if I for example move `end`, I'd like `start` to stay on the same spot it was before.

Comment: But you cannot preserve center position in this case

Comment: I don't want to. I want to calculate new center position with end or start unchanged.

Comment: It is impossible to build an arc with two points (start and end). You have do define one more point or some rule

Comment: I know the old position of changed point, old radius and old center point. Would that be enough?

Comment: Three freely moveable points don't make that much sense. Two (start and end) points and a value (displacement of center relative to mid between start and end) should be better to work with.

Comment: And how should old positions and radius influence on new parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure if explained correctly what I want to achieve. Fortunately I found a software that allows that and recorded behaviour I'd like to have in my application. Could you please take a look at this:http://imgur.com/a/YmF96

Comment: Note that software is not magic and uses third point on the arc - arc always goes through old middle of arc. You did not state that you wanted such behavior.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough. Could you please point me somewhere where I can learn how to perform such operation?

Comment: added C++ example and preview to my answer. (nice approach I will implement it into my vector editors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the how it should work video shows that there are 3 points on circle 2 endpoints and one in between them (not circle center) so you need transformation between that and your representation. So the video has:

- `A,B` - endpoints
- `M` - mid point on the arc

And you got:

- `A,B` - endpoints
- `C` - center
- `a0,a1` - endpoint angles assuming `a0<a1`
- `r` - radius

The `A,B` are identical and `a0,a1` are computed by `atan2` as you already do. Now how to compute the rest:

```
a = 0.5*(a0+a1);
M.x = C.x + r*cos(a);
M.y = C.y + r*sin(a);
```

To compute radius from `A,B,M` you can solve this quadratic system:

```
(A.x-C.x)^2 + (A.y-C.y)^2 = r
(B.x-C.x)^2 + (B.y-C.y)^2 = r
(M.x-C.x)^2 + (M.y-C.y)^2 = r
```

where `C.x,C.y,r` are the unknowns. Or use this simple linear approach instead:

- [how to find a bitangent, point of concavity and center of gravity of concavity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23327333/2521214)

From that you will obtain `C` and `r = |A-C| = |B-C|`

**Here small C++ demo for this:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline bool Intersect2DRayRay(double *pp,double *p0,double *p1,double *p2,double *p3) // pp = intersection point
    {
/*
    p0+(p1-p0)*s = p2+(p3-p2)*t
    ---------------------------
    s = ( (p2-p0)+(p3-p2)*t )/(p1-p0)
    t = ( (p0-p2)+(p1-p0)*s )/(p3-p2)
    ---------------------------------
    s = ( (p2[0]-p0[0])+(p3[0]-p2[0])*t )/(p1[0]-p0[0])
    t = ( (p0[1]-p2[1])+(p1[1]-p0[1])*s )/(p3[1]-p2[1])
    ---------------------------------------------------
        (p1[0]-p0[0])*(p0[1]-p2[1]) + (p1[1]-p0[1])*(p2[0]-p0[0])
    t = ---------------------------------------------------------
        (p1[0]-p0[0])*(p3[1]-p2[1]) - (p1[1]-p0[1])*(p3[0]-p2[0])

        (p1[1]-p0[1])*(p0[0]-p2[0]) + (p1[0]-p0[0])*(p2[1]-p0[1])
    t = ---------------------------------------------------------
        (p1[1]-p0[1])*(p3[0]-p2[0]) - (p1[0]-p0[0])*(p3[1]-p2[1])

    s = ( (p2[0]-p0[0])+(p3[0]-p2[0])*t )/(p1[0]-p0[0])
    s = ( (p2[1]-p0[1])+(p3[1]-p2[1])*t )/(p1[1]-p0[1])
    ---------------------------------------------------
*/
    double s,t,a,b;
    const double _zero=1e-30;
    a=((p1[0]-p0[0])*(p3[1]-p2[1]))-((p1[1]-p0[1])*(p3[0]-p2[0]));
    b=((p1[1]-p0[1])*(p3[0]-p2[0]))-((p1[0]-p0[0])*(p3[1]-p2[1]));
    if (fabs(a)>=fabs(b)) { b=a; a=((p1[0]-p0[0])*(p0[1]-p2[1]))+((p1[1]-p0[1])*(p2[0]-p0[0])); }
    else                  {      a=((p1[1]-p0[1])*(p0[0]-p2[0]))+((p1[0]-p0[0])*(p2[1]-p0[1])); }
    if (fabs(b)<=_zero) // paralelne alebo nulove ciary
        {
        double x0,x1,x2,x3,y0,y1,y2,y3;
        if (p0[0]<p1[0]) { x0=p0[0]; x1=p1[0]; } else { x0=p1[0]; x1=p0[0]; }
        if (p0[1]<p1[1]) { y0=p0[1]; y1=p1[1]; } else { y0=p1[1]; y1=p0[1]; }
        if (p2[0]<p3[0]) { x2=p2[0]; x3=p3[0]; } else { x2=p3[0]; x3=p2[0]; }
        if (p2[1]<p3[1]) { y2=p2[1]; y3=p3[1]; } else { y2=p3[1]; y3=p2[1]; }
        if (x1-x0>_zero)
            {
            if (x3<x0) return false;
            if (x2>x1) return false;
            if (fabs(y3-y0)<=_zero) return true;
            return false;
            }
        if (y1-y0>_zero)
            {
            if (y3<y0) return false;
            if (y2>y1) return false;
            if (fabs(x3-x0)<=_zero) return true;
            return false;
            }
        if (fabs(y3-y0)+fabs(x3-x0)<=_zero) return true;
        return false;
        } else t=a/b;
    a=p1[0]-p0[0];
    b=p1[1]-p0[1];
    if (fabs(a)>=fabs(b)) { b=a; a=(p2[0]-p0[0])+((p3[0]-p2[0])*t); }
    else                  {      a=(p2[1]-p0[1])+((p3[1]-p2[1])*t); }
    if (fabs(b)<=_zero)
        {
        b=1/0;                  // error possibly due to low accuracy or horrible input
        } else s=a/b;
//  if ((s<0.0)||(s>1.0)) return false;
//  if ((t<0.0)||(t>1.0)) return false;
    pp[0]=p0[0]+(p1[0]-p0[0])*s;
    pp[1]=p0[1]+(p1[1]-p0[1])*s;
    return true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const double _point_r=8.0;  // select and render point size
const double _point_rr=_point_r*_point_r;
enum _arc_sel               // selection ID
    {
    _arc_sel_none=-1,
    _arc_sel_a,
    _arc_sel_b,
    _arc_sel_m,
    };
class arc
    {
public:
    double ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy,mx,my;
    int sel;    // mouse selection ID
    bool _sel;  // is sel locked? (durring editation)
    arc()   { _sel=false; sel=_arc_sel_none; }
    arc(arc& a) { *this=a; }
    ~arc()  {}
    arc* operator = (const arc *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //arc* operator = (const arc &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    // A,B,M -> C
    void compute_c()
        {
        double pp[2],p0[2],p1[2],p2[2],p3[3];
        // center is intersection of normals from line midpoints
        p0[0]=0.5*(ax+mx); p1[0]=p0[0]+ay-my;
        p0[1]=0.5*(ay+my); p1[1]=p0[1]-ax+mx;
        p2[0]=0.5*(bx+mx); p3[0]=p2[0]+by-my;
        p2[1]=0.5*(by+my); p3[1]=p2[1]-bx+mx;
        if (Intersect2DRayRay(pp,p0,p1,p2,p3))
            {
            cx=pp[0];
            cy=pp[1];
            p0[0]=mx-ax;
            p0[1]=my-ay;
            p1[0]=bx-mx;
            p1[1]=by-my;
            p2[1]=(p0[0]*p1[1])-(p0[1]*p1[0]);
            // swap A,B if wrong winding =  sighn of z coordinate of (p0 x p1)
            if ((p0[0]*p1[1])-(p0[1]*p1[0])>0.0)
                {
                p0[0]=ax; ax=bx; bx=p0[0];
                p0[0]=ay; ay=by; by=p0[0];
                     if (sel==_arc_sel_a) sel=_arc_sel_b;
                else if (sel==_arc_sel_b) sel=_arc_sel_a;
                }
            }
        }
    // A,B,C -> M
    void compute_m()
        {
        double x,y,r,a0,a1,am;
        x=ax-cx; x*=x;
        y=ay-cy; y*=y;
        r=sqrt(x+y);
        a0=atan2(ay-cy,ax-cx);
        a1=atan2(by-cy,bx-cx);
        if (a1<a0) a1+=2.0*M_PI;
        am=0.5*a0+a1;
        mx=cx+r*cos(am);
        my=cy+r*sin(am);
        }
    // VCL render (can ignore this)
    void draw(TCanvas *scr)
        {
        double x,y,r;
        x=ax-cx; x*=x;
        y=ay-cy; y*=y;
        r=sqrt(x+y);
        scr->Pen->Color=clSilver;
        scr->Arc(cx-r,cy-r,cx+r,cy+r,ax,ay,bx,by);
        r=_point_r;
        scr->Pen->Color=clBlue;
        if (sel==_arc_sel_a) scr->Brush->Color=clAqua; else scr->Brush->Color=clDkGray; scr->Ellipse(ax-r,ay-r,ax+r,ay+r);
        if (sel==_arc_sel_b) scr->Brush->Color=clAqua; else scr->Brush->Color=clDkGray; scr->Ellipse(bx-r,by-r,bx+r,by+r);
        if (sel==_arc_sel_m) scr->Brush->Color=clAqua; else scr->Brush->Color=clDkGray; scr->Ellipse(mx-r,my-r,mx+r,my+r);
        scr->Pen->Color=clRed;
        scr->Brush->Color=clDkGray;
        scr->Ellipse(cx-r,cy-r,cx+r,cy+r);
        }
    // VCL mouse handler (can ignore this)
    double mx0,my0; TShiftState sh0;
    void mouse(double mx1,double my1,TShiftState sh1)
        {
        double x,y;
        int q0,q1;
        // point selection
        if (!_sel)
            {
            sel=_arc_sel_none;
            x=ax-mx1; y=ay-my1; if ((x*x)+(y*y)<=_point_rr) sel=_arc_sel_a;
            x=bx-mx1; y=by-my1; if ((x*x)+(y*y)<=_point_rr) sel=_arc_sel_b;
            x=mx-mx1; y=my-my1; if ((x*x)+(y*y)<=_point_rr) sel=_arc_sel_m;
            }
        // left mouse button handler
        q0=sh0.Contains(ssLeft);
        q1=sh1.Contains(ssLeft);
        if ((!q0)&&(q1))    // click start
            {
            _sel=1;
            mx0=mx1;
            my0=my1;
            }
        if (q1)             // click move
            {
            x=mx1-mx0;
            y=my1-my0;
            if (sel==_arc_sel_a) { ax+=x; ay+=y; compute_c(); }
            if (sel==_arc_sel_b) { bx+=x; by+=y; compute_c(); }
            if (sel==_arc_sel_m) { mx+=x; my+=y; compute_c();}
            }
        if ((q0)&&(!q1))    // click end
            {
            _sel=0;
            }
        // remember last mouse state
        mx0=mx1; my0=my1; sh0=sh1;
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just ignore or rewrite the **VCL** stuff. It uses `math.h` here preview:

[image: preview]